# Pass an array or object via the URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering if it's possible to pass an array of IDs or strings via the URL attribute in a Backbone Collection?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/api/mystuff/categoryID',

        getStuff: function(ArrayOfThings) {
            this.fetch({ url: this.url + '/' + ArrayOfThings
            });
        }
    });
```

And call it like this:

```
 ArrayOfThings = [12342, 364556, 333236, 33763, 4212456433221, 335]
 var myCollection = new MyCollection();
 myCollection.getStuff(ArrayOfThings);
```

So I tried that, but my URL string looks like this:

> `api/mystuff/theCategoryID/12342,364556,333236,33763,4212456433221,335`

Which my server does not like.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the desired URL you're looking for?

Comment: that's a great question...I don't know to be honest.  But the server needs the data in the array in order for it be processed.  I may have to re-think this. Thanks, I needed another pair of eyes to look at this.

Comment: If you absolutely need the data like that, I would either use a POST request, or format it with "-" instead of commas and let the server do the parsing. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Maybe it could be structured like `api/mystuff/theCategoryID?categories=12342,364556,333236,33763,4212456433221,335` that's more inline with a standard GET request with parameters. It's really a server-side concern more than Backbone. What language and web server does your server use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing your page from a link, consider attaching an html5 data- element to the button.  Then when you call the function that builds your page, the data-element will be available on the event that's generated when you build that page.

I have a similar situation where I have to get UID's to my new page for rendering, selecting purposes and this is exactly the pattern I use to accomplish that goal

For example:

```
<button id='link' data-id='S|1,S|2'>Button</button>
```

Code in view for the page I want getting the data:

```
    pageNeedingUIDs: function(ev) {
         var uid = $(ev.currentTarget).data('id')
         ...
    }
```